# Combine multiple React components

Tags: reactjs

How do I display multiple components on my page currently `refundTimeLine` shows `[Object object]`.

Code:

```
let tdWidth = "25%"
let refundTimeLine = "";
transactionJourney.map((trans) => {
    if(trans.key=="refund") {
        trans.value.forEach((refundRow) => {
            console.log(refundRow);
            refundTimeLine+= <TimelineStatus tdWidth={tdWidth} statusObj={{date: refundRow.date, time: refundRow.time}} statusClass={statusIcon} tickClass={tickClass} text={"Refund of "+refundRow.amount} />
        })
    }
})

console.log(refundTimeLine);
return (
    <tr>
        <TimelineStatus tdWidth={tdWidth} statusObj={_this.getStatusObject('paymentInitiated')} statusClass={statusIcon} tickClass={tickClass} text={"Payment Initiated"} />
        <TimelineStatus tdWidth={tdWidth} statusObj={_this.getStatusObject('paymentSuccessful')} statusClass={statusIcon} tickClass={tickClass} text={"Payment Succesful"} />
        <TimelineStatus tdWidth={tdWidth} statusObj={_this.getStatusObject('settlementInProgress')} statusClass={statusIcon} tickClass={tickClass} text={"Settlement in Progress"} />
        <TimelineStatus tdWidth={tdWidth} statusClass={statusIconDisabled} tickClass={tickClass} text={[_this.props.transactionData.paymentBreakUp.amountSettled+" will be",<br/>,  "credited to your bank",<br/>,"account in 72 hours"]} />
        {refundTimeLine}
    </tr>
)
```

Please help new to React

Answer (score 2):

**Reason is**, you initially defined `refundTimeLine` as `string` and then appending the `react` component by using `+=`. Instead of that define `refundTimeLine` as an `array` and push the `react` component inside that.

Write it like this:

```
let refundTimeLine = [];
transactionJourney.map( (trans, i) => {
   if(trans.key=="refund") {

      trans.value.forEach((refundRow, j) => {
          refundTimeLine.push(<TimelineStatus
                                  key={i + '_' + j}   //add a unique key 
                                  tdWidth={tdWidth} 
                                  statusObj={{date: refundRow.date, time: refundRow.time}} 
                                  statusClass={statusIcon} 
                                  tickClass={tickClass} 
                                  text={"Refund of "+refundRow.amount} 
                              />)
      })

   }
})
```

**Suggestion**:

1- You are using `map` here, instead of that use `forEach`.

2- Don't forgot to assign the **unique key** to each ui element created inside `loop`, it will help `React` to identified the item that changed, if any change happens, it will improve the performance.

Comment: You will have to add `key`.

Comment: By the way, `refundTimeLine.length` will be more than enough to generate a key :)

Comment: @Sulthan awesome dude, absolutely we can use that, i think that will be much better than `i + '_' + j` :)

Comment: Technically, in a more functional way, you can generate the values using `const refundTimeLine = transactionJourney.filter(trans => trans.key == "refund").map(trans => trans.values).reduce((aggregator, array) => aggregator.concat(array), []);` and then just call `map` this array into components.

Comment: @Sulthan ohh man, this one will be the best solution, you taught me alot today, it will reduce the complexity by a greater amount. I think you should add this as a answer :)